# Implement get_program_accounts using BanksClient

Tags: rust, getprogramaccounts, solana-program-test

BanksClient doesn't have a `get_program_accounts` method. Is there a way to mimic it?

Comment: Actually I see that `Bank` has a `get_program_accounts` method, so perhaps this should just be added to `BanksServer` and `BanksClient`?

Comment: Yeah that sounds like the right approach!